# Content is getting reverted to old content automatically

Tags: publishing

In our sitecore website, we have English and Japanese as versions.
We are updating content for Japanese version and not using English. We have updated content for some of the items throughout the day. All of a sudden the updated content is replaced with older content for that item. This behavior is intermittent.

We are sure, that we are updating the right content, there is only one user who is updating the content. The updated content is saved and we are doing incremental publishing with all sub-items. The updated content is shown on the site for sometime and then after a while the older content appears.

Can you please let us know if you have come across such cases and what could be the possible cause and fix for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the Publishing Viewer for the item(s) in question to see if they have an unpublish (end) date on the 'updated' version(s).

Comment: Do you have only 1 server? If no, it may be that the content is cached on a server and is still reflecting the old one. Also, are your changes to the items still available on the master database? Moreover, check the target database to see if the updated item is still there. If yes, then it is a cache issue on your servers

Comment: Thank you. We are actually on Azure PaaS with CM and CD on different instances. The old content is visible even on the master in edit mode. So I believe it may not the caching issue.

Comment: @SurendarE so you mean that even on the master database, the updates get lost?

Comment: Sounds more like databases being restored, or database replication that is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible causes for a behavior just like you described:

1- Someone is manually overwriting the content. Based on your question I'm assuming this is not the case

2- The version it's being published is not the right one. Please go to Publishing viewer and selec the start and end date to see which version is publishable

3- Expanding #2 if you go to publishing restriction you can have a good picture on which versions are publishable and when

4- You have a task scheduled that is publishing content async and causing you this behavior.

5- if none of these address your issue you can always reffer to the Sitecore logs and they will give a good idea on what's going on with the publishing.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. 1 to 3 are not the causes of our issue. We are checking.. Can you please let me know if there is any default scheduled task that is usefd for publishing content?

Comment: Considering the comments that have been added to the thread I'm starting to think that the publishing is not the issue here. CAn you please validate on the logs to see if there is any publishing overriding the proper content? My guess is you won't find anything there which would be a good lead to database not properly setup

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs, views. Those are learnings indeed.

We found that, the master and web DBs are not in sync. There are more entries in Web than in Master. If any updates done directly on Web for any reasons, the publishing messup inevitable.

The best way is to edit the content in master, clear the Sitecore cache and publish the content.

If you are not able to see the change in web, then check the publishing queue table. If there are more than 1000 entries, truncate the table and try publishing it again.  Never attempt to make the change in Web directly.

Once again thank you all.